# How to pronounce, "Tut! Tut!"

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, spelling-pronunciations

In older manuscripts, sometimes somebody says, "Tut! Tut!"

Was this actually pronounced as written (as if referring to the famous King of Egypt)?

Comment: That's still used. It's the traditional orthographic representation of the repeated [dental click](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_clicks) that indicates disapproval, disappointment, etc. It's the ‘sucking your tongue’ sound.

Comment: Think of 'nut' 'nut' , as in the nut you eat, and simply replace the n, with T, T as in the T in tower, T-ower

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I that's *tsk*.

Comment: @deadrat Same thing. _Tsk_ is more common in AmE, _tut_ more common in BrE, but they usually refer to the same sound.

Comment: I second @Gary, "Tut tut" can also be pronounced as written, at least in AmE.

Comment: The Winnie the Pooh stories often mangle the language intentionally, but the [linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NitBpJaom5k) video clip is a good example of the phrase spoken as spelt. (It occurs at around 2:10 in the clip.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not known to me as anything but a "double click".
Such sounds cannot be written accurately in English.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_consonant)
It may be that some try to pronounce *tut, tut* as it is written, but i do not recall having ever heard the attempts.[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZT3b2Bwg6NU)
However the verb "to tut" does seem to sound "tut".